# python, without method overloading, howto?

Tags: python, overloading

I want to write a function named size() which will accept either a file name or a list of filenames and return the size of the file or sum of its sizes respectively. How to do this without function overloading which is not available in python?

thanks

suresh

Comment: @eyquem Users should be encouraged to use proper English grammar and spelling, but your attitude is rather confrontational. Don't bash the new users, just tell them what is expected of them.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the support. I am a new user here. I completely understand that proper English grammar and spelling must be used. But if the questions would be subject to hair splitting analysis of the language constructs, I am afraid, it would deter many....

Comment: @suresh Well, thank you to keep so kind. I appreciate people that are able to admit their little faults. Hence I can appreciate myself, because I do a lot of faults. - I will delete all my comments, you will be as white as snow again :-) to begin on stackoverflow. If you correct **their** with **its**, I even will upvote your question !

Comment: @eyquem With my English knowledge, I could not see if **its** is better. That's why I did not change it earlier. But I guess **its** is more precise. To err is human right? But our endeavor should be to reduce it as much as we can....(As learned from other masters)

Comment: @suresh I was thinking to _"will accept either a file name or a list of filenames, and return its size or the sum of their sizes respectively"_ But I won't go on playing as if I was a master of English

Comment: @suresh Pythonically, what you describe is ``end_of_life = reduce(operator.sub, endeavour, initializer=great_amount_of_human_errors)`` :-)

Comment: @eyquem :) I couldnt help laughing man!!! Meanwhile let me tell you something pythonic. Based on the inputs I got from this discussion, I was trying to write a function which will give me file size if the argument is a file or directory or a list of file/directory. I hit the recursion limit while testing..I guess too much recursion Python does not like.

Comment: @suresh I'm not very skilled in recursion. If you have a problem, you should ask a new question. Regards.

Comment: @eyquem Thanks. Let me cross check my code and then I will post if I am still in trouble...

Comment: How is it possible that at the time when you call that method you don't know if your argument is a str or a list of str?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using overloading internally as it is most intuitive to a user of the function

```
import os

def file_size(files):

    if isinstance(files, str):
        files = [files] # enlist

    size = 0
    for f in files:
        size += os.path.getsize(f)

    return size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print file_size(__file__)
    print file_size([__file__, __file__])
    print file_size([])
```

Comment: Wont I be unnecessarily holding all the size values in the list sizes and hence wasting memory, while I only need their sum of sizes? I am not sure whether my thinking is right or not as I am new to Python....

Comment: I see "sum of sizes" - i didn't understand the question due to the typo. Yes instead of keeping all sizes, it is possible to just keep the sum. In this case, the batch_call variable is not useful because the type of the output doesn't change if the input is a string or a list

Comment: @selvin _" i didn't understand the question due to the typo"_ . Nor did I. Which is the reason I couldn't answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
def size(*files):
    for file in files:
        print file
```

`*files` is a special argument type which will catch all arguments into a list. Thus, if you call `size` like this:

```
size("file1.txt", "file2.xml")
```

`files` will be a list containing `file1.txt` and `file2.xml`. If you call it with only one argument, it will still be placed in a list.

To call the function with a list of files, use the same operator, but use in when you call the function:

```
file_list = ["file1.txt", "file2.xml"]
size(*file_list)
```

Comment: This is not correct.  The OP wishes to send either a string or a list of strings.  Your code assumes multiple args...

Comment: @gahooa, this method allows you to send both a single argument, and a list of arguments. What is your point?

Comment: Maybe I'm taking the term `list` too literally, but as I read the original post, it says he wants either `size(string_with_filename)` or `size(list_of_filenames)`.  A poor design choice.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code presented in this answer is a good design and I recommend that @suresh just use it.

Comment: In this method, I will have to prefix a * to the argument if it is a list right? But then I do not know if the input is going to be a list or not apriori. So I guess this will not work.

Comment: @gahooa Why did you say that its a poor design choice? My situation is: I am reading a single or a list of filenames from a configuration file and I need to find the sum of these filenames. So I need a method which would just accept either and give me the answer...

Comment: @suresh The input is going to be a list always. If you pass in 1 argument, it's going to be a list of 1 argument. If you pass in none, it's going to be a list of 0 arguments.

Comment: @suresh, how do you determine if the read file(s) should be in a list or just a single file? As I see it, you can't read from a file and have *no* way to know if you read a list of files or a single file. I suggest you make your reading function return a list no matter what, even if there's only one file, for consistency.

Comment: @Harpyon You are right. But I originally wrote a size function for a single (non list) argument. Then I wanted to extend it if the argument is a list with one or more elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
def size(files):
    # convert to a list if only one item given
    if not hasattr(files,'__iter__'):
        files = [ files ]

    for fname in files:
        ...do something with fname...
```

**EDIT**: this variant has the advantage that you can add more parameters (e.g. `min_mtime`) to this function in the future

Comment: @Holzner, I just now discovered that `hasattr('any_string','__iter__')` is `True`. So one need to use `isinstance` or something like that....

Comment: in fact I realized that it returns `True` in python 3 but `False` in python 2.6 ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you asked for.  However, I think it's a poor design choice.  Remember the zen of python...

```
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
```

In concept, just check the input argument for what type it is

```
def size(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        retval = ... #get size of arg
        return retval
    else:
        retval = []
        for f in arg:
           retval.append(...)  #get size of each file
        return retval
```